# How to ensure JpegCallback is finished writing before trying to access the picture

Tags: android, file-io, callback, camera, photo

I'm writing an application with one of the key features being taking a photo and writing it to a file, then reading that photo into a base64 array (all in the one button click). The problem being that when i initiate the onclick to take a photo it will return from this function before the onPhotoTaken() function has received the image and written it to the storage directory specified.

I have added log outputs at several stages in the code and it is clear that the onclick takePhoto function is exiting before the onPhotoTaken() function that it calls is finished.

The android documentation states that you need to wait for JpegCallback to finish returning before you can restart the preview but I am having trouble getting it to wait for the write to finish.

code:

```
public static void takePhoto(){
    fCamera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
    Log.d("capture", "photo was captured");
    // Set the image callback
    Log.d("this one is", "being called");

}

static PictureCallback jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    // Function for handling the picture
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera fCamera){
            //fCamera.stopPreview();            
            Log.d("is this", "not being called ??? probably");
            File imagePath;
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            // create the filename with extension
            String fileName = "IMAGE_1.bmp";
            // Create / Find the storage Directory for our pictures
            //storageDir = context.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            // Create it if it doesn't exist
            // Create the image file
            imagePath = new File(storageDir, fileName);
            String finalPath = imagePath.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.d("location", finalPath);
            if (!imagePath.exists()) {
                if (!imagePath.mkdirs())
                    Log.d("@string/app_name", "Failed to create File");
                return;

            }

            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //finalImage.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            try {
                out.write(data);
                Log.d("write", "photo was written");
                out.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

Log cat:

```
 10-13 12:55:39.185: D/capture(7126): photo was captured
 10-13 12:55:39.185: D/this one is(7126): being called
```

These are the only log outputs that occur.

Comment: You mean that `jpegCallback.onPictureTaken()` is never called? That could be because the camera is not ready to take pictures. E.g., preview is not started.

Comment: I'm certain the preview is started and just in case I started it again just before the takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback) function is called.
The problem remains that after it calls this it returns before the onPictureTaken can start. Apparently it takes a few seconds to take the image and return the callback.

Comment: I have a log output in the main after the whole function set is called and it will output before the photo writing output occurs. (If i edit the onClick to have nothing following the taking photo function set). So i'm deducting that the problem is what i have stated but i still cannot seem to fix it with while and if statements.

Comment: I still don't understand your problem. Do you see `jpegCallback.onPictureTaken()` called at all? At what delay after `takePhoto()` is done?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, by taking a photo and then try to create a thumbnail and store it to the media gallery.
As it's defined in here(developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture) takePicture is an asynchronous proccess, so you have to derive your program logic and mandate the sequence.
This can be implemented with AsyncTask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
In [this](https://www.workreloaded.com/2011/06/how-to-use-the-android-camera/) example, the code inside onPostExecute method will be executed  after camera.takePicture (so you are sure that onPictureTaken from PictureCallback is done).